# How to get unique values of Observable Array property - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an Angular application and it has a service that gets data from a fake API and it returns an array of objects like the below :

```js
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "quidem molestiae enim"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "omnis laborum odio"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "non esse culpa molestiae omnis sed optio"
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "eaque aut omnis a"
  },
  {
    "userId": 4,
    "id": 6,
    "title": "natus impedit quibusdam illo est"
  },
  ]
```

What I  want is to get the unique  values of **userId**  property without duplication, so I should get these values  :
1
2
3
4

So how to implement this in Angular4 ..

Here's my code :

1- Service.ts: Which returns all the data without filtration the duplicated values.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import "rxjs/Rx";



@Injectable()
export class AlbumsService {


  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { }
  serveLink:string = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums"

  getUniqueUserIDs():Observable<IAlbums[]>
  {
    return this._http.get<IAlbums[]>(this.serveLink).map(response=>response)
  }

}
```

2-FilterComponent.ts: Here I log the results in the console by subscribing to the observable.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlbumsService } from '../albums.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter-albums-by-user-id',
  templateUrl: './filter-albums-by-user-id.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter-albums-by-user-id.component.css']
})
export class FilterAlbumsByUserIdComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _albumsService:AlbumsService) { }

  ngOnInit() 
  {

    this._albumsService.getUserIDs()
    .subscribe 
     ((response)=>
      {
        console.log(response)
      }
    )

  }
}
```

Other important question, in this case, where should I write the logic? 
In the Service method or in the Component's subscription?

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the business context. Will you need all the responses (including duplicates) elsewhere in the application? Say for a count of? In which case it is best to put the filter in the component subscription. On the other hand, if the rest of the application should not be knowing about the duplicates, service is the best place to put the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Using new Set via ES6 ,

```js
const response = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "quidem molestiae enim"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "omnis laborum odio"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "non esse culpa molestiae omnis sed optio"
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "eaque aut omnis a"
  },
  {
    "userId": 4,
    "id": 6,
    "title": "natus impedit quibusdam illo est"
  },
  ];

const uniqueIds = [...new Set( response.map(obj => obj.userId)) ];
console.log(uniqueIds);
```

and you should do this in the component level.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map`,`distinct`, and `toArray`:

```
return this._http.get<IAlbums[]>(this.serveLink).map(t=>t.userId).distinct().toArray();
```

Comment: I got this error : Property 'userId' doesn't exists on type 'IAlbum[]'